# Use PL/pgSQL to loop through a query a list or range of dates

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to run the below query for each of the last 120 months. It's a simple count of records active at a 'snapshot' point in time, as given by the opened and closed dates...

```
select
    date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month) as snapshot_date,
    count(*) as count_active
from table1
where opened_date <= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month) 
and closed_date > date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month)
```

My regular approach would be to use 'union', like this...

```
select
    date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month) as snapshot_date,
    count(*) as count_active
from table1
where opened_date <= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month) 
and closed_date > date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month)

union

select
    date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '2' month) as snapshot_date,
    count(*) as count_active
from table1
where opened_date <= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '2' month) 
and closed_date > date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '2' month)

union

select
    date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '3' month) as snapshot_date,
    count(*) as count_active
from table1
where opened_date <= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '3' month) 
and closed_date > date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '3' month)
...
```

But copying and posting the code, and changing each of the date ranges is obviously not feasible. How can PL/pgsql be written to loop a list/range of dates through a query and return a single output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate series` to achieve this:

```
with cte(c) as (
select generate_series(1,120)
)
select
    date_trunc('month', current_date - cte.c* interval '1' month) as snapshot_date,
    count(*) as count_active
from table1, cte
where opened_date <= date_trunc('month', current_date - cte.c * interval '1' month) 
and closed_date > date_trunc('month', current_date - cte.c * interval '1' month)
group by 1
```

Above query will return the records only from the month in which transaction happens. If you want all the months in between then :

```
with cte(date_) as (
select generate_series(date_trunc('month', current_date - 120* interval '1' month), date_trunc('month', current_date),interval '1' month) 
)
select cte.date_ "snapshot_date", count(id) "count_active"
from cte left join table1 on opened_date<=date_ and closed_date>date_
group by 1
order by 1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c1801d87f9b394f9d6a5da36a83dda8d)